# Sum of two families of uniform integrable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are two families of u.i(uniform integrable) random variables defined on the same probability space. Is $\{X_n+Y_n\}$ u.i?

## Proof

Given $$\mathbb{E}[|X_n|\,I_{|X_n|\geq K}]\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4} ,\qquad \mathbb{E}[|Y_n|\,I_{|Y_n|\geq K}]\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4}  $$
Since $|X_n+Y_n|\,I_{|X_n+Y_n|\geq 2K}\leq 2|Y_n|\,I_{|Y_n|\geq K}+2|X_n|\,I_{|X_n|\geq K}$
Then $$\mathbb{E}[|X_n+Y_n|\,I_{|X_n+Y_n|\geq 2K}]\leq\mathbb{E}[2|Y_n|\,I_{|Y_n|\geq K}+2|X_n|\,I_{|X_n|\geq K}]$$$$=2\mathbb{E}[|Y_n|\,I_{|Y_n|\geq K}]+2\mathbb{E}[|X_n|\,I_{|X_n|\geq K}]\leq 2 \frac{\varepsilon} {4}+2 \frac{\varepsilon} {4}= \varepsilon$$
Thus $\{X_n+Y_n\}$ is ui.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239684/linear-combinations-of-sequences-of-uniformly-integrable-functions @saz

Comment: If you look at the answer and scroll down you will see this inequality

Comment: Im not really convince why though

Comment: I see, thanks...

Comment: Does this look okay? @saz

Comment: Well, basically that's exactly what Did suggested in his answer. What do you mean by "you are not convinced"? That you do not know how to prove the inequality?